# Книга с примерами по С

Tags: c, книги

Просьба: можете подсказать книгу по "С" ту, которую читали вы? В нете литературы много, а я человек зеленый еще в С. Мечусь между всем, не знаю, что выбрать). Было бы неплохо книжку с примерами.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из собственного опыта:

С. Пратта "Язык программирования С" - понятный, подробный, с большим количеством примеров и упражнений.

Керниган и Ритчи "Язык программирования С" - классическое описание от авторов языка. Хорош как справочник, но не для первоначального обучения, т.е. слишком краток и сух в изложении, даются сразу довольно сложные примеры, нет упражнений.

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо! :)

Comment: С. Пратта "Язык программирования С"  --- хм, что-то не могу её найти в нете... есть только для С++

Comment: У меня бумажный вариант. Но инете видел.

Comment: Меня посещают смутные сомнения. Вроде её нет в электронном варианте.

Comment: Google "пратта язык программирования с скачать" Результатов: примерно 31 100 (0,25 сек.)

Answer (score 3):

Мне очень понравилась Б. Керниган, Р. Пайк. "Практика программирования". Исключительно толковая книга, но может быть не для начального уровня.

Comment: Спасибо. Посмотрим)